# How to update Edit Text in DialogBar from MainFrame in Visual C++/MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I created a C++ app with SDI using MFC in Visual C++ 2015. The app contains a dialogbar.  Which contains an Edit Text. I just want to update value of Edit Text from MainFrame.  Please provide a solution

I tried to update Edit Text using below code

```
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, "hi");
```

But does not update value in Edit Text

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? Perhaps you should take a refresher of [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)? And of course, don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not misunderstand my question.  Kindly go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering you have dialog resource ID of your dialog bar in project resource and having CDialogBar member variable in mainframe, will try to explain this.

You will have following code in `int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` function.

```
if ( ! m_wndMyDialogBar.Create(this, IDD_DIALOGBAR, CBRS_TOP , IDD_DIALOGBAR)) //IDD_DIALOGBAR resource id of dialog bar
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create dialog bar from CMyDialogBar class\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

once you have valid dialogbar object then you can just do following to set window text to edit box:

```
m_wndMyDialogBar.GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText("TEXT YOU WANT"); //Where IDC_EDIT1 is id of text box present on IDD_DIALOGBAR resource.
```

Comment: Yes it is working.  Thanks bro

Comment: Welcome Man!..........